# Pattern matching on slices

Tags: rust, matching

I did something like this, which works:

```
let s = " \"".as_bytes();
let (space, quote) = (s[0], s[1]);
```

I wanted to do something like this

```
&[space, quote] = " \"".as_bytes();
```

But it gives me the error

```
slice pattern syntax is experimental (see issue #23121)
```

Is it possible to do something similar?

Comment: as described in the error the syntax is experimental, so you'd better not use it for now. Why you want to use the slice pattern?

Comment: Does it mean it is not implemented yet? I turns out that I don't need to do it anymore because I found a better solution for my problem. However, I was still curious about why it is not working. And I might need to use it some day.

Comment: @x4rkz: Experimental means that it is not yet decided whether it would be implemented as is, implemented in another way, or not implemented at all. It's in flux.

Comment: It is implemented but the semantics could change anytime. To prevent accidentally breaking your code, you need to explicitly tell the compiler to opt-in for these unstable features to use it.

Comment: Did you go look at [issue 23121](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/23121), as the error message says?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error tells you, slice pattern syntax is experimental. This means either the semantics are not clear or the syntax might change in the future. As a result, you need a nightly version of the compiler and to explicitly request that feature:

```
#![feature(slice_patterns)]

fn main() {
    match " \"".as_bytes() {
        &[space, quote] => println!("space: {:?}, quote: {:?}", space, quote),
        _ => println!("the slice lenght is not 2!"),
    }
}
```

Also note that you can't just write `&[space, quote] = whatever` anyway because there is a possibility that `whatever` is not the right length. To make the pattern matching exhaustive, you need a `_` case or a case with `..`. What you tried would give another error:

```
error[E0005]: refutable pattern in local binding: `&[]`, `&[_]` and `&[_, _, _, ..]` not covered
 --> src/main.rs:4:9
  |
4 |     let &[space, quote] = " \"".as_bytes();
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ patterns `&[]`, `&[_]` and `&[_, _, _, ..]` not covered
  |
  = note: `let` bindings require an "irrefutable pattern", like a `struct` or an `enum` with only one variant
  = note: for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-02-refutability.html
help: you might want to use `if let` to ignore the variant that isn't matched
  |
4 |     if let &[space, quote] = " \"".as_bytes() { /* */ }
```

---

As of [Rust 1.26](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1260-2018-05-100) you *can* pattern match on an array instead of a slice. If you [convert the slice to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48129565/155423), you can then match on it:

```
use std::convert::TryInto;

fn main() {
    let bytes = " \"".as_bytes();

    let bytes: &[_; 2] = bytes.try_into().expect("Must have exactly two bytes");
    let &[space, quote] = bytes;

    println!("space: {:?}, quote: {:?}", space, quote);
}
```