# How to convert a slice into an array reference?

Tags: arrays, rust, slice

I have an `&[u8]` and would like to turn it into an `&[u8; 3]` without copying. It should reference the original array. How can I do this?

Comment: `[&x[0], &x[1], &x[2]]`?

Comment: That's an [&u8; 3].

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: Also see the related but different [How to get a slice as an array in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25428920/155423)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As of Rust 1.34, you can use `TryFrom` / `TryInto`:

```
use std::convert::TryFrom;

fn example(slice: &[u8]) {
    let array = <&[u8; 3]>::try_from(slice);
    println!("{:?}", array);
}

fn example_mut(slice: &mut [u8]) {
    let array = <&mut [u8; 3]>::try_from(slice);
    println!("{:?}", array);
}
```

Comment: If you're passing it into a function that expects such a parameter, you can also use `try_into().unwrap()` to avoid the need to write out the array type, and if you're sure the slice is large enough.

Comment: It would be nice to add explicitly does this require a copy?

Comment: @EvanCarroll it cannot perform a copy. If it did, then returning a reference would be impossible as the copy would be destroyed.

Answer (score 9):

***EDIT: `TryFrom`/`TryInto` has been stabilized as of Rust 1.34. Please see @shepmaster's answer for an updated method.***

Just to re-emphasize, this can't be done without unsafe code because you don't know until runtime that the slice has three elements in it.

```
fn slice_to_arr3<T>(slice: &[T]) -> Option<&[T; 3]> {
    if slice.len() == 3 {
        Some(unsafe { &*(slice as *const [T] as *const [T; 3]) })
    } else {
        None
    }
}
```

This can't be generic over the length of the array until [const generics](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2000-const-generics.html) are implemented.

Comment: I'd quibble over the phrasing "this can't be safe". It is most definitely *safe* — as long as you check the length of the slice. If it actually could never be safe, then it should never be written in the first place. It's a pedantic argument but the concept of "safety" is muddled enough for Rust newcomers that I find it worth pointing out.

Comment: He might have meant "this can't be non-unsafe".

Comment: Yes I agree. Maybe better phrasing is _cannot be done without unsafe code_.

Comment: Nothing can be "done without unsafe code" by that logic since the stdlib necessarily needs unsafe code, everything one shall ever use internally has that. I think the correct phrasing is "this problem has no total solution"; any solution to it has to be partial and account for the error case where the slice does not have at least 3 elements, somehow.

Comment: @Zorf the phrasing I like to use is to draw a difference between *safe* and *sound*. The code is not safe because you have to use the `unsafe` keyword, no way around that. But it is sound because we check the length of the slice, as the compiler is trusting us to do.

Comment: It definitely can be done in safe code; see Shepmaster's answer. It could also have been done in safe code prior to Rust 1.34, with a loop over the elements or with [copy_from_slice](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.copy_from_slice).

Comment: As one of the Rust newcomers mentioned above, both the answer and the comments are extremely confusing to me. If someone wouldn't mind explaining, 1) why does this require an `unsafe` block when `.try_into().unwrap()` seems to work fine (maybe this is how it had to be done prior to Rust 1.34?), 2) since this answer checks that the slice is of length 3 before doing anything, how do comments about partial solutions due to slice length apply to this?

Comment: @Codebling:
1. Yes, prior to stabilizing `TryInto` this was the only way, but nowadays it's definitely clearer to just call `.try_into()`. Don't include the `.unwrap()` unless you are 100% confident that the slice is the right length -- always better to check rather than crash the program. You can actually [see](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.67.0/src/core/array/mod.rs.html#261) that the conversion is implemented using essentially the code in this answer.

2. Are you referring to @Zorf's comment? Besides the quibble about wording I *think* they were backing me up re: needing the length check.

Comment: @durka42 thanks! Really appreciate the explanation!

Answer (score 9):

They [arrayref](https://docs.rs/arrayref/) crate implements this.

Here's an example, you can of course use it in different ways:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate arrayref;

/// Get the first 3 elements of `bytes` as a reference to an array
/// **Panics** if `bytes` is too short.
fn first3(bytes: &[u8]) -> &[u8; 3] {
     array_ref![bytes, 0, 3]
}
```