# How can I turn a GenericArray<T, ?> into an array of the same length?

Tags: arrays, rust, type-conversion

I'm computing the SHA256 of a given data:

```
let hashvalue = sha2::Sha256::digest(&data);
```

After computing it, I want to put this value into a field of my struct:

```
let x = Hash { value: hashvalue };
```

However, the `Hash` struct expects the type of value `[u8; 32]`, while my `hashvalue` variable is of type `GenericArray<u8, ?>`. How can I convert `hashvalue` into the correct type? I tried to use `as [u8; 32]` and `arr!` but it didn't work.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

If you don't know the length of the array, convert the `GenericArray` into a slice and then convert the slice into an array (only for arrays of length 32 or less [before Rust 1.47](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.47.0/RELEASES.md#libraries)):

```
use sha2::Digest; // 0.9.3
use std::convert::TryInto;

fn main() {
    let hashvalue = sha2::Sha256::digest(&[3, 2, 6, 4, 3]);
    let x: [u8; 32] = hashvalue.as_slice().try_into().expect("Wrong length");
    println!("{:?}", x);
}
```

See also:

- [How to get a slice as an array in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25428920/155423)
- [How to convert a slice into an array reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48129565/155423)
- [Is it possible to control the size of an array using the type parameter of a generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28136739/155423)

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation for `GenericArray`](https://docs.rs/generic-array/0.13.2/generic_array/struct.GenericArray.html), I assumed that you could use `hashvalue.into()`, but I did not manage to get it to compile.

Non-idiomatic alternative:

```
use digest::Digest; // 0.7.6
use generic_array; // 0.13.2
use sha2; // 0.7.1

fn main() {
    let hashvalue = sha2::Sha256::digest(&[3, 2, 6, 4, 3]);
    let x: [u8; 32] = [
        hashvalue[0],
        hashvalue[1],
        hashvalue[2],
        hashvalue[3],
        hashvalue[4],
        hashvalue[5],
        hashvalue[6],
        hashvalue[7],
        hashvalue[8],
        hashvalue[9],
        hashvalue[10],
        hashvalue[11],
        hashvalue[12],
        hashvalue[13],
        hashvalue[14],
        hashvalue[15],
        hashvalue[16],
        hashvalue[17],
        hashvalue[18],
        hashvalue[19],
        hashvalue[20],
        hashvalue[21],
        hashvalue[22],
        hashvalue[23],
        hashvalue[24],
        hashvalue[25],
        hashvalue[26],
        hashvalue[27],
        hashvalue[28],
        hashvalue[29],
        hashvalue[30],
        hashvalue[31],
    ];
}
```

Comment: That's because `sha2` 0.8 uses `digest` 0.8, which uses `generic-array` 0.12.0 which does not implement `Into` — that's only 0.13. Likely another case of people not specifying the most compatible versions of crates in their Cargo.toml but instead just always picking the newest (even when they could support multiple).

Comment: Also, I added versions to your imports assuming you were using the playground. However, note that the playground doesn't have the newest versions of all these crates. If you weren't using the playground, please fix my corrections so that they are accurate.