# How to get first 128 bits of sha256 as u128, without a Result?

Tags: arrays, rust, slice, sha256

This works, but is very convoluted:

```
let mut hasher = Sha256::new();
hasher.update(foo);
hasher.update(bar);
let hash = hasher.finalize();
let hash_array: [u8; 16] = hash[0..16].try_into().expect("slice with incorrect length");
let hash128 = u128::from_le_bytes(hash_array);
```

Is there a way of doing this without:

```
let hash_array: [u8; 16] = hash[0..16].try_into().expect("slice with incorrect length");
```

I'm handling a condition which cannot happen, as I know that sha256 produces 32 bytes.  How can I tell the compiler that?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59376378/how-can-i-turn-a-genericarrayt-into-an-array-of-the-same-length/59378107#59378107) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48129565/how-to-convert-a-slice-into-an-array-reference) looks very similar to your question. Does it answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert a buffer of a slice of bytes (&\[u8\]) to an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307474/how-can-i-convert-a-buffer-of-a-slice-of-bytes-u8-to-an-integer)

Comment: [`read_u128`](https://docs.rs/byteorder/1.3.4/byteorder/trait.ByteOrder.html#tymethod.read_u128) would let you skip the step of creating the hash array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way but it's a bit convoluted currently: both Rust arrays and `GenericArray` deref' to slices, so that's what you get when you slice (`hash[..16]`), which then requires a failible conversion back to an array as the compile-time length information is lost.

*However* `GenericArray<T,N>` implements `AsRef<[T;N]>` and arrays are `Copy`, so from a `GenericArray` you can somewhat easily get an array of the same size (by just deref'ing the reference), and thus the question is how to get a `GenericArray` of the proper size when slices don't work.

Turns out generic_array provides [a split](https://docs.rs/generic-array/0.14.3/generic_array/sequence/trait.Split.html). I think I'm missing something to its use because it's a bit gnarly but there you go:

```rust
    let hasher = Sha256::new();
    let hash = hasher.finalize();
    let (head, _): (GenericArray<_, U16>, _) = Split::split(hash);
    let hash128 = u128::from_le_bytes(*head.as_ref());
```

(note: I'm wilfully using the UFCS form of `Split::split` rather than the method form to limit confusion with `slice::split`).

Comment: "`GenericArray<T,N>` implements `AsRef<T;N>`" - should it be `AsRef<[T; N]>` instead?